# Embed Get Your Guide Widget in Angular2 component

Tags: angular, typescript, widget, embed

I am trying to embed a "Get Your Guide" Widget in Angular2.

I can add the script in index.html and it gets requested, but I don't know how to add it to the HTML of the component.

```
<script async defer src="//widget.getyourguide.com/v2/core.js" onload="GYG.Widget(document.getElementById('gyg-widget'),{'q':'Paris'});"></script>
```

I have tried in the HTML:

```
    <div id="gyg-widget"></div>
```

And in the typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var GYG: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-excursions',
  templateUrl: './excursions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./excursions.component.scss']
})

export class ExcursionsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    new GYG.Widget(document.getElementById('gyg-widget'),{'q':'Paris'});
  }
}
```

But this is pure guessing and it doesn't work.

Error: Error in ./ExcursionsComponent class ExcursionsComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: GYG is not defined
ReferenceError: GYG is not defined
    at ExcursionsComponent.ngOnInit (excursions.component.ts:20)

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular-cli and I have solved this problem by

1. Downloading the Get your Guide library from widget.getyourguide.com/v2/core.js and storing it as lib/gyg.js
2. Adding the following lines to angular-cli.json:

   "scripts": [
       "lib/gyg.js"
     ],

This replaces the  part from above. I was not able to load the script directly from an external server as suggested by Get Your Guide.